# SQL to pull 24 years old customers

Tags: teradata

I need to pull the records of all the customers whose age is less than and equal to 24 years from today’s date in teradata.

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: `where birthdate >= add_months(current_date, -24*12)`

Comment: Hi, It is working. Thank You.
Can you please describe the above syntax?

Comment: `add_months` adds or subtracts months from a date, `-24*12` equals -24 years